# Can obj.__dict__ be inspected if the class has a __dict__ variable?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, introspection, internals

I am interested in whether there is a way to introspect a Python instance infallibly to see its `__dict__` despite any obstacles that the programmer might have thrown in the way, because that would help me debug problems like unintended reference loops and dangling resources like open files.

A simpler example is: how can I see the keys of a `dict` subclass if the programmer has hidden `keys()` behind a class of its own? The way around that is to manually call the `dict` `keys()` method instead of letting inheritance call the subclass's version of the method:

```
# Simple example of getting to the real info
# about an instance

class KeyHidingDict(dict):
    def keys(self):
        return []  # there are no keys here!

khd = KeyHidingDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
khd.keys()       # drat, returns []
dict.keys(khd)   # aha! returns ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now my actual question is, how can I see the `__dict__` of an instance, no matter what the programmer might have done to hide it from me? If they set a `__dict__` class variable then it seems to shadow the actual `__dict__` of any objects inherited from that class:

```
# My actual question

class DunderDictHider(object):
    __dict__ = {'fake': 'dict'}

ddh = DunderDictHider()
ddh.a = 1
ddh.b = 2
print ddh.a        # prints out 1
print ddh.__dict__ # drat, prints {'fake': 'dict'}
```

This false value for `__dict__` does not, as you can see, interfere with actual attribute setting and getting, but it does mislead `dir()` by hiding `a` and `b` and displaying `fake` as the object's instance variable instead.

Again, my goal is to write a tool that helps me introspect class instances to see “what is really going on” when I am wondering why a set of class instances is taking so much memory or holding so many files open — and even though the situation above is extremely contrived, finding a way around it would let the tool work all the time instead of saying “works great, unless the class you are looking at has… [description of the exceptional situation above].”

I had thought I would be able to infallibly grab the `__dict__` with something like:

```
dict_descr = object.__dict__['__dict__']
print dict_descr(ddh, DunderDictHider)
```

But it turns out that `object` does not have a `__dict__` descriptor. Instead, the `subtype_dict()` C function seems to get separately attached to each subclass of `object` that the programmer creates; there is no central way to name or fetch the descriptor so that it can be manually applied to objects whose class shadows it.

Any ideas, anyone? :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me think further! So that is a way out if, in the inheritance hierarchy `object` → `A` → `B`, the object `B` is the one shadowing its instances' `__dict__` attributes. But am I correct that your idea does *not* help if it is class `A` that is defining a misleading `__dict__` class attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm happy with how simple this is:

```
>>> class DunderDictHider(object):
...     __dict__ = {'fake': 'dict'}
... 
>>> ddh = DunderDictHider()
>>> ddh.a = 1
>>> ddh.b = 2
>>> 
>>> print ddh.a
1
>>> print ddh.__dict__
{'fake': 'dict'}
```

The problem is that the class is cheating?  Fix that!

```
>>> class DictUnhider(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> ddh.__class__ = DictUnhider
>>> print ddh.a
1
>>> print ddh.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

And there it is.  This completely fails though, if the class defines any slots.

```
>>> class DoesntHaveDict(object):
...     __slots__ = ['a', 'b']
... 
>>> dhd = DoesntHaveDict()
>>> dhd.a = 1
>>> dhd.b = 2
>>> 
>>> print dhd.a
1
>>> dhd.__class__ = DictUnhider
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'DoesntHaveDict' object layout differs from 'DictUnhider'
>>>
```

Comment: `__slots__` can still define a `__dict__` that will work as the normal, default slot of the same name.  also, you could mask the `__slots__` var even if there isn't a real slots setup in the class.

Comment: Since the whole point was to introspect objects *without* changing them, I had already discarded the idea of making adjustments to the class — even in the absence of other threads that might be using the object at the same time as I am examining it, this solution would require that I switch out the `__class__` of whole groups of objects while I can them for resources and open files. But I will think more about whether I should really be ignoring this possibility out-of-hand. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This one is based on Jerub answer in this topic:
[What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

You can achieve what you're looking for with metaclasses.

First you need to create a metaclass:

```
def test_metaclass(name, bases, dict):
    print 'The Class Name is', name
    print 'The Class Bases are', bases
    print 'The dict has', len(dict), 'elems, the keys are', dict.keys()

    return dict
```

of course the prints are not necessery.

Then let me introduce your new DunderDictHider:

```
class DunderDictHider(object):
    __metaclass__ = test_metaclass
    __dict__ = {'fake': 'dict'}
```

Now you have access to all initialized elems by `repr(DunderDictHider)`

The output (with `print repr(DunderDictHider)` line):

```
The Class Name is DunderDictHider
The Class Bases are (<type 'object'>,)
The dict has 3 elems, the keys are ['__dict__', '__module__', '__metaclass__']
{'__dict__': {'fake': 'dict'}, '__module__': '__main__', '__metaclass__': <function test_metaclass at 0x1001df758>}
```

Each time you can try

```
if '__dict__' in repr(DunderDictHider)
```

to know whether this class tries to hide its `__dict__` or not. Remember, that repr output is a string. It can be done better, but that's the idea itself.

Comment: I say it's not fair to call it a metaclass if it's a function. Sure, it's valid, but it's not a *class*.

Comment: I might be a bit confused — my question was about examining the state of (a) object instances that (b) inherit from arbitrary classes that other programmers have written and that I cannot trust to have avoided techniques that would make introspection difficult. But:

(a) I see no object instance here in your answer.
(b) If I do not control the classes that programmers are writing, how am I going to control the metaclasses?